# Logging out through nested routers with react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've been struggling to implement a simple logout in my app build with `react-native` and the navigator `react-navigation`

My navigators look like this

```
AuthNavigator (StackNavigator)
----DrawerNavigator (DrawerNavigator)
    ----TabsNavigator (TabNavigator)
        ----Tab1Navigator (StackNavigator)
        ----Tab2Navigator (StackNavigator)
        ----Tab3Navigator (StackNavigator)
        ----Tab4Navigator (StackNavigator)
```

(Is this clear enough ?)

My logout button is located in a screen into the `Tab4Navigator` and I do need to go back up to the `AuthNavigator` and I can't really figure it out ...

I've been thinking of using a package like [react-native-restart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-restart) but I don't feel like this is really 'clean'...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and the only workaround that worked for me was to manually reset the navigation the the reducer.

```
const nav = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGOUT': {
      return {
          index: 0,
          routes: [{key: 'Init', routeName: 'AuthNavigator'}]
        };
    }
    default:
      return AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state) || state;
  }
};
```

Where `LOGOUT` is a custom action you fire from `Tab4Navigator` when you want to logout and `AuthNavigator` is the route of the screen you want to show when the user is logged out. This assumes you use Redux to manage the navigation state as described here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux .